# How to delete a residual Ubuntu directory from Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I'm using Windows 7. After installing (and uninstalling) Ubuntu on my laptop, I found that it left a folder called ".Trash-1000" on my H drive. I cannot remove it: if I try to delete it from Explorer, it says:

> The file name you specified is not valid or too long.
>   Specify a different file name.

If I try to remove it from the command line, this is what happens:

```
H:\>rmdir .Trash-1000 /S /Q
.Trash-1000\files\Screenshot from 2013-09-24 11:57:32.png - The filename, direct
ory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
.Trash-1000\files\Screenshot from 2013-09-24 12:03:45.2.png - The filename, dire
ctory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
.Trash-1000\info\Screenshot from 2013-09-24 11:57:32.png.trashinfo - The filenam
e, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
.Trash-1000\info\Screenshot from 2013-09-24 12:03:45.2.png.trashinfo - The filen
ame, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The files mentioned there are the contents of that folder. Using quotes around the folder name yields the same result. Trying to delete any of the sub-folders results in the same error, and trying to remove any of the files inside results in "No such file or directory".

As I said before, I no longer have Ubuntu installed. How can I remove this folder?

Comment: Have you tried deleting it from within Explorer?  At the very least, you should be able to do it from a Linux LiveCD.

Comment: This is probably caused by the `:` which is not allowed to be in a file's name.  I agree with the idea to use a Linux Live CD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a Linux Live CD or install CygWin and use the `rm` command on it.

Comment: In cygwin, running the command `$ rm -rf H:/.Trash-1000` results in the error `Device or resource busy` for the subfolder `files` and `Directory not empty` for the subfolder `info`. Haven't tried a live CD, I will report on that later.

Comment: Cygwin uses the same operating system functions as Explorer and Command Prompt.

Comment: I had to delete it using the terminal in a live CD, and that worked. So, solved.